# Active Admin Sidebar Dynamic Title

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I have an active admin sidebar that shows a list of post_likes as  links.

```
  sidebar "Post Likes", only: [:show, :edit] do
    ul do
      post.post_likes.each do |post_like|
        li link_to(post_like.creator.full_name, admin_post_like_path(post_like.id))
      end
    end
  end
```

It looks and works just fine but I'd like to add the number of post_likes into the sidebar's title with something like this:

```
sidebar "Post Likes #{@post.post_likes_count}", only: [:show, :edit] do
```

Unfortunately I get a "undefined method `post_likes_count' for nil:NilClass". I should be sitting on a single post record but it acts like I am not. Two lines down in the code I have access to the post object.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: `sidebar "Post Likes #{resource.post_likes_count}", only: [:show, :edit] do`

or

`sidebar proc {"Post Likes #{resource.post_likes_count}"}, only: [:show, :edit] do`

Comment: Option number two worked for me. Good old proc! Thanks for your help.